# HTML entity not rendering in the live server but it renders correctly in the local machine

Tags: html, utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters, html-entities

In the local machine it shows:

`Baby Nursery Accessories and Décor Private Label Amazon FBA Business`

But in the live server it shows:

`Baby Nursery Accessories and D&eacute;cor Private Label Amazon FBA Business`

I already put these in both of them:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<meta charset="utf-8">
```

I've checked both on Firefox and Chrome, and the issue is still the same. By the way, I use PHP. Maybe that would help.

**UPDATE**

It happens only in a textbox and in modal.

Why could that happen?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was caused by a javascript in my code using `$(.selector).text()` instead of `$(.selector).html()` so the HTML entities didn't get rendered